# Cross-Platform can't find a custom folder path

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, directory

I am using C# and Xamarin cross-platform. I created a new folder "Images" and I added some jpg files. When I try 'GetFiles' getting exception because it can't find folder path.
I also try to put the folder on the project core above put still the same.

```
  string directory = @"~/Images/";
            List<Image> HandCards = new List<Image>();

            foreach (string myFile in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = FileImageSource.FromFile( myFile);

                HandCards.Add(image);
            }
```

[image]
[image]

**Update 1**

After Nick Kovalsky Answer I move the folder but still the same error.

[image]

Comment: You are asuming how the OS you run on handles paths. In paritculary what the Directory seperator is, wich wildcards are used, etc. I can not even tell right now what the "~" in your code is supposed to represent. The path class is all about formating paths in a OS agnostic way.

Comment: The "~" in web applications and windows forms representing root folder of the application.

Comment: The ~ represents "current Path" in HTML and HTML only. It does not belong into a C# side path.

Comment: @Christopher `in HTML` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code you are parsing shared library resources from shared code, while having images in native android library. 
Better move em to shared library: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17854/shared-images-in-shared-project

**EDIT:**

to build a list of all images at startup:

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var ImagesFiles = new List<string>(); 
foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
            {
                if (res.Contains(".jpg"))
                {
                    ImagesFiles.Add(res);
                }
            }
```

to set images at runtime, first at init set your global variable `AssemblyName`:

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
AssemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
```

then you can load images by name:

```
    public static ImageSource ImageFromResources(string subfolder, string filename)
    {
        var generatedFilename = AssemblyName + $".Images.{subfolder}.{filename}";
        return ImageSource.FromResource(generatedFilename);
    }
```